# How to generate mp4 file from image sequence (jpg for example) using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I have an image sequence sample001.jpg, sample002.jpg, ..., sample400.jpg. How to build an mp4 video file from them using `ffmpeg` and `Ruby on Rails`?

Comment: As for ffmpeg, see [How do I encode single pictures into movies?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)

Comment: I did that. But how to use this feature of `ffmpeg` from `Rails`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that the `Rmagick` gem is doing almost what I've wanted. It can save my sequence to an avi format (which is OK for me too).

1) Load your sequence:

`sequence = ImageList.new("sample001.jpg", "sample002.jpg", ..., "sample400.jpg")`

2) Genearte avi file:

`sequence.write("sequence.avi")`

3) Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use system command to run `ffmpeg` command line in ruby. 
`system("ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg")` or `exec` or `backticks`